# pandas dataframe groupby and agg to obtain a value if conditions in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'ID1':['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A'],
                       'ID2':['a','a','a','aa','aaa','aaa','b','b','b','b'],
                       'ID3':['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6','c7','c8','c9','c10'],
                       'condition1':[1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1],
                       'condition2':[80,85,88,80,70,83,85,90,90,70]})
```

df_test
[image: df_test]

I want to pick values in ID3 after group by ['ID1','ID2','condition1'] and (1):if there is only one row in the group, then it will be picked (such as c4), (2)if there is one more rows in the group, then it will be picked at the condition2 is max in the group (such as c3, c6,c9, and c8). the result will like this:

```
df_test_result = pd.DataFrame({'ID1':['A','A','A','A','A','A'],
                       'ID2':['a','a','aa','aaa','b','b'],
                       'condition1':[2,1,1,1,2,1],
                       'condition2':[85,88,80,83,90,90],
                        'ID3':['c2','c3','c4','c6','c8','c9']})
df_test_result
```

[image: df_test_result]

the process appears to be that way, but it is too ineffective (because I need to contact them together):

```
groups = df_test.groupby(['ID1','ID2','condition1'])
for group in groups:
    dfi = group[1][group[1]['condition2']==group[1]['condition2'].max()]
    print(dfi,'\n')
```

[image: process]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition (1) generalises as (2), so you can always just look at the first row in the group according to `condition2`:

```
(
    df_test
    .sort_values("condition2", ascending=False)  # sort everything by condition2
    .groupby(["ID1", "ID2", "condition1"])
    .first()  # select first row in each group (now ordered by condition2)
    .reset_index()  # reset groupby columns
)
```

Comment: Ah, Thank you so much. I see.